# How to draw 5 multiplications with numbers between 0-10?

Tags: python

I have tried quite many ways to solve this one but I am actually not understanding the core thing of this problem. Can anyone please explain . The problem is
#Make a multiplication program. The program draws 5 multiplications with numbers between 0-10. The calculations are printed on the screen. The user then responds to the calculation task one at a time and press Enter. Finally, the program prints the calculations and the correct answers, the feedback, e.g emoji :-) and tells you how many went right.

I have tried something like this
{
`from random import seed
from random import randint

seed(1)

for _ in range(10):
value = randint(0, 10)*5
print(value)}

`

Comment: What *do* you understand about it?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: I am understanding i have to generate random numbers and the program will generate a multiplication number from that .Is it correct??

Answer (score 2):

Sounds something like this (wrap it in a loop to restrict number of times it asks if you want):

```
import numpy as np

# OPTIMIZATION
random_list = np.random.randint

num_1 = random_list(11)
num_2 = random_list(11)

answer = int(input(f'What is {num_1} times {num_2}'))
while not answer == num_1 * num_2:
    answer = int(input('Incorrect. Please try again.'))

print("Correct!")
```

Comment: Numpy? For simple random numbers? That's like trying to kill a mosquito with a thermo-nuclear weapon :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo helpful

Comment: @footfalcon don't forget to cast the answer as an ´int´

Comment: Just one thing I'd check, random numbers are almost always half-open ranges so, if you want ten included, you may have to use `11` as the top end. And I didn't mean to disparage your answer, just pointing out that you don't *need* to install numpy for something like this.

Comment: Hmm, to keep the program running, maybe you should wrap it in a while loop or a function (and keep it going via recursion)

Comment: @paxdiablo thanks for the added tip (I was just answering on the fly and am so used to using numpy that it just came out). Have edited to 11 as well.

Comment: Awesome, I'd upvote that if I hadn't already done so :-)

Comment: @theX thought I'd leave something for the OP to try (hence just put it in the text before the code). Happy to accept if you'd like to edit my answer.